# Magento 2: Disable Full Screen Gallery on Mobile

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I'm trying to disable the full screen gallery on magento 2.2.1

The code below does not work. I tried everything,

```
<var name="breakpoints">
        <var name="mobile">
            <var name="conditions">
                <var name="max-width">767px</var>
            </var>
            <var name="options">

                <var name="options">
                 <var name="allowfullscreen">false</var>
                 <var name="arrows">false</var> <!-- Turn on/off arrows on the sides preview (true/false) -->
                 <var name="nav">thumbs</var> 
                </var>
            </var>
        </var>
    </var>
```

The other part of the code such as thumbs or arrow do work.

It's this part :

```
 <var name="allowfullscreen">false</var>
```

This does nothing.